# Problems with categorical variable in fviz_famd_var function of factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

```
fviz_famd_var(res.famd, "quali.var", col.var = "black")
```

I have same problem, did you get a solution?

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘ALQ’, ‘Artery’, ‘AsbShng’, ‘AsphShn’, ‘BLQ’, ‘BrkFace’, ‘CBlock’, ‘Ex’, ‘Fa’, ‘Feedr’, ‘Gd’, ‘GLQ’, ‘HdBoard’, ‘ImStucc’, ‘LwQ’, ‘MetalSd’, ‘Mod’, ‘Norm’, ‘Plywood’, ‘Po’, ‘PosA’, ‘PosN’, ‘Rec’, ‘RRAe’, ‘RRAn’, ‘RRNn’, ‘Sev’, ‘Stone’, ‘Stucco’, ‘TA’, ‘Unf’, ‘VinylSd’, ‘Wd Sdng’
```

I tried with `row.names=NULL`, but it didn't solve my problem.